# 2sxc DNN - QueryString attribute filter

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm using the blog app of 2sxc DNN module.

It already has querystring by author and tags, i was wondering if it would be possible todo one with PublicationMoment with Year only.

I only want to show post by year, so thought doing a query string would be helpful 
**(example: xxxx/blog/?PublicationMoment=2015)**, however in visualquery i don't know how to go about it, as QueryString is through a relationship filter by Entity not by attribute.

Anyhelp in this regard would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be easy... here's how you can start going on about it...

While you're experimenting, please create a completely new query which only queries this. You need this, because you'll be tinkering around a bit and you want to be sure you're not confusing yourself with other parts of the query.

You should be able to create a value-filter where the publication-moment `between` and then `date1 and date2`. While tinkering, I suggest you really do a `2016-01-01 and 2017-01-01`. once that works, start replacing the static values `2016-01-01` with `[QueryString:Start]` or with `[QueryString:Year]-01-01`....then build on that.

ok?

Comment: Awesome, works great.

ValueFilter
Attribute: PublicationMoment
Value: [QueryString:Year]-01-01 and [QueryString:Year]-12-01
Operator: Between